# Set Up Http Server on Iphone

Tags: iphone, http, http-live-streaming, httpserver

Can we set up HTTP server on iPhone for audio streaming . I need to set up my iphone as a http server where i have to upload the audio buffer and  do the live http streaming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Apple's [HTTP Live Streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592485/http-live-streaming/6593834#6593834) is based on static files, you can use a HTTP Server. There are at least a couple: [cocoahttpserver](http://code.google.com/p/cocoahttpserver/), [CocoaHTTPServer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CocoaHTTPServer/Listings/CocoaHTTPServer_m.html), and you can read [how to do yours](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/simple-extensible-http-server-in-cocoa.html).

Or you can program the whole thing using socket programming and bonjour, so clients can find each other. Apple has an example project to send pictures between iphones whose name I don't remember. :P You can read more about it in [Network Programming: Chapter 7 - iPhone SDK Application Development](http://oreilly.com/iphone/excerpts/iphone-sdk/network-programming.html)

Socket programming is close to C, and needs a bit more work than UIKit.

Comment: Thanks john for ur help , i found all these and also two more but they always show the localhost machine IP address.

Comment: CocoaHTTPServer binds to INADDR_ANY (as seen in TCPServer.m) which means it answers to localhost *and* to the IP in the local network. Find the IP of the iPhone in the local network and give it a try. Or use cocoahttpserver and call using the local domain.

Answer (score 0):

i have successfully built/config'd/run lighttpd on iPad and had it serve an HTTP Live Stream as well. it was pretty straight forward... just get the source, massage the config, make, then fiddle with the install and it just worked.