# Create interactive videos in iPad - An app for product demo

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, video, mobile

I would like to create videos that needs to run on an iPad native app. The app needs to show a demonstration of a product through iPad. It needs to be interactive as well. I know we can do these in Flash, since Flash is not supported in iPad what are my options?

I appreciate any guidelines or hints. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to create interactive videos for iOS is to use Apple's [HTTP Live Streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592485/http-live-streaming) technology. You have to create a video, [embed metadata](http://jmacmullin.wordpress.com/2010/11/03/adding-meta-data-to-video-in-ios/), play it using `MPMoviePlayerController` or `AVPlayerItem`, and then display clickable areas in response to metadata notifications.

Metadata should contain coordinates for the element you are tracking, eg: a dress, and a identifier for the product. You overlay this info with a clickable subview that reveals more information about the product. There are several applications of this kind in iTunes, here is [one](http://itunes.apple.com/es/app/videos-interactivos-moda-elcorteingles/id417714134).

Once you get a working product and weeks-time of videos, the most difficult part is to perform motion tracking with the less possible human interaction. One approach is to use Adobe After Effects, another is to code your own solution based on OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

You could use an [MPMoviePlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) with no controls, on loop.

Here's a solution I  thought of using interactive HTML popover's over the video:

You could have a data store (say an `NSDictionary`), with playback times as keys.
The values could then be a custom class, which includes all the necessary data for an interactive popover on the video.

Your custom class could look something like this

```
@interface InteractivePopover : NSObject
{
    NSString *snippetTitle;
    NSString *htmlData; // could include links etc.
    CGPoint popoverDisplayPoint;
    // other styling attributes etc.
}
```

Now, when a user taps the video, it pauses it at the next 'interactive' point (by looking for the next key after the current playback time), and displays (animates on) all the popups, which you set before to show off different parts of the product.

That class might be your data store, then you create another class to handling displaying, animating, controlling, sizing (etc) these interactive popovers. It would create a UIWebView for the HTML. It would also control direction, and indication of the source point for your popover.

This is clearly very expandable because you could put images, embedded content etc into the HTML for these interactive popovers.

Anyway, that's how I would do it.

Answer (score 0):

Though flash will not run on ipad you can still create apps for it with flash cs5 .