# How to use HTTP live stream?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

My one app is rejected and it says..

`We found that your app does not use the HTTP Live Streaming protocol, with a baseline stream of 64 kbps, to broadcast streaming video, as required by the App Store Review Guidelines.`

I searched almost every thing but still i am confused and don't have any clear view about `HTTP  Live Streaming`

I have read many documents but i didn't get any idea where to start and how to use **HTTP live streaming tool** and all other stuff.. :(

Can any one give me a clear solution for my confusion??
How can i use `HTTP Live Streaming` in my app??
How do i `segment` my videos and then how to add them in to `playlist`??

Any help please..
If anyone help me in this then it would be a great help..!!

Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: You expect a detailed answer to a vague question in an hour?!

Comment: Actually i want an easy way to understand where to start and what to do first.. because i am little bit new to this technology and very much confused about `HTTP Live Streaming`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your video to transport stream (.ts) using FFmepg and then use mediafilesegmenter to split the video and create a playlist:

```
mediafilesegmenter -t 10 myvideo-iphone.ts
```

This will generate one .ts file for each 10 seconds of the video plus a .m3u8 file pointing to all of them.
See the answer at [HTTP LIve Streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592485/http-live-streaming/6593834#6593834) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Apple supplies a lot of [documentation and tools](https://developer.apple.com/streaming/) to help with HTTP Live Streaming. The tools convert a video to a format suitable for streaming from most web servers.