# MPMoviePlayerController for Mac?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos

I use MPMoviePlayerController on iOS all the time for HTTP Live streaming.  I'm just starting Mac Development and can only see a QuickTime player view.  I was reading on here and some of the posts say you need to add some stuff via command line and then do some other stuff. 
[HTTP LIve Streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592485/http-live-streaming)

Is all that really necessary?

Doesn't Mac have a solution for playing video as simple as MPMoviePlayerController?

I noticed AVFoundation is available in Lion, does that mean it wont work on OS's prior to Lion?  If so, what is the alternative for video playback without AVFoundation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you provided has nothing to do with displaying HTTP Live streaming. It has to do with preparing the video and serving it over HTTP Live streaming. For playback look into the quicktime frameworks, particular, [the QTMovie class](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/QuickTime/Reference/QTKitFramework/Classes/QTMovie_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003799).