# HTTP Live Streaming of static file to iOS device

Tags: mpmovieplayercontroller, http-live-streaming, chunked, http-chunked, streaming-video

I'm trying to understand the "chunked" aspect of [HTTP Live Streaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming) a static video file to an iOS device. **Where does the chunking of the video file happen?**

**Edit**: from reading [HTTP LIve Streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592485/http-live-streaming) and a bit more of https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-07 it sounds like the video file is split into .ts segments on the server. Or the m3u8 playlists can specify byte offsets into the file (apparently using `EXT-X-BYTERANGE`).

Here's what I understand of this process after reading [Apple's HLS description](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/FrequentlyAskedQuestions/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008332-CH103-SW1) and https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-07:

- A static file lives on my server. It has the proper audio/video encoding (H.264 and AAC).
- I'll pass an `m3u8` playlist to the media player (`MPMoviePlayer` or similar) in my app.
- The app will "reload the index" during media playback. In other words the app will request additional segments to play.
- each 10 second segment is in an [MPEG Transport Stream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-TS) container.

My understanding of this process is incomplete (and perhaps incorrect). Any additional info is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you asking for?? Info???
-The app is not reloading the index but playing it... using the M3U8 file that switches the correct encoded file. That way you only have to make a connection between the mediaPlayer and the "Manifest File" for example...

```
NSURL    *fileURL    =   [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://techxvweb.fr/html5/AppleOutput/2012-03-10-j23-dax-smr-mt1-m3u8-aapl.ism/manifest(format=m3u8-aapl)"];
moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
/* Inset the movie frame in the parent view frame. */
CGRect viewInsetRect = CGRectInset ([self.view bounds],0.0, 0.0 );
[[moviePlayerController view] setFrame: viewInsetRect ];
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
[moviePlayerController play];
```

where the NSUrl is the url to your manifestFile... note that I'm adding:

***/manifest(format=m3u8-aapl)***

to the original manifest file, what parses the "ISM" file to the correct M3U8 syntax

```
   NSURL    *fileURL    =   [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://techxvweb.fr/html5/AppleOutput/2012-03-10-j23-dax-smr-mt1-m3u8-aapl.ism/manifest(format=m3u8-aapl)"];
```

Comment: Have you faced any issue on slow network? I am doing same but video not playing on bad network (2G) but audio continues. Please help...

Comment: I think the Edge is not enough to play your videos, you should maybe generate an output with a very very low quality to support it