# iPhone/iPad Downloading and Playing Simultaneously

Tags: ios

I want to Download and Streaming and Downloading the video simulteniouslly by App.
There video are heavy so Converted into m4u8 format and using the VOD Live streaming cocept to play them in MPMoviePlayer.
How to download there live streaming Video simulteniouslly with palying .
Can you suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

FOllowing are the code to play the movie,  Hope this is useful..

```
 NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"<Video URL>"];
        [self playMovie:fileURL];

-(IBAction)playMovie:(NSString *) theURL 
{
    NSURL    *fileURL    =   [NSURL fileURLWithPath:theURL];
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:moviePlayerController];

    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
    moviePlayerController.useApplicationAudioSession = NO;
    moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
    [moviePlayerController play];
}

- (void)moviePlaybackComplete:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                  object:moviePlayerController];

    [moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [moviePlayerController release];
}
```

**To Make the Video capable of streaming**

1. Video should be of .mp4 format.
2. All videos should be converted using the Miro Video Converter in Mac (Or similar converters) and make it compatible to play in iPhone, iPad and Android devices.
   Converted videos will play in mobile devices.  However, the video will play only after the full video is downloaded from the server.
3. To make the video streaming, the video's metadata has to be moved to the beginning of the video.  To achieve this, we have to use a tool called Medadata mover to encode the video.
4. Then the final video is compatible of streaming and able to play in all mobile devices.
   Then the video have to be FTP'ed to the desired web hosting.  for example demo.com/videos/test.mp4.
5. Then the video can be configured in iPhone or android app and can be streamed.

**See More for Apple Live Streaming** 
[HTTP LIve Streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592485/http-live-streaming)

Comment: thanks a lot, But my video are heavy,so i am using the Live Streaming protocol to plat the Video and Downloading also .......

Comment: Yes I agree.. you have to encode your video using metadata mover so that your video will be streaming..i.e it will be streaming..   Please let me know if you have any questions..  NOTE : metadatamover is a tool for windows to make the metadata of the movie to the beginning of the movie.

Comment: Is it steaming now correctly..   If so please feel free to upvote my answer so people will find it useful..

Comment: My problems are:---in cellular network how to handle heavy video of size 40MB, so i used the concept of live streaming and converted video  in there  format, but in cellular network still too much time is consumed by these.

Comment: second part how i can download there sequence of file , to store in device memory

Comment: OK kuldeep..  I have used this video streaming technique for videos which have 100MB..  It worked for me..  Apple also have some live streaming technique..  I dont know that.. Please post the answer once you find it.. Thanks...

Comment: Hi Dilip,About the video Live streaming we have to convert those video in requires .m3u8 format.and upload to server.

Comment: Please can u explain me how you are streaming the 100mb video?

Comment: Hai Kuldeep..  Please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592485/http-live-streaming this gives live streaming procedure.  For stativ videos to convert to .m3ua you can follow this link http://www.ioncannon.net/programming/452/iphone-http-streaming-with-ffmpeg-and-an-open-source-segmenter/