# Audio streaming in ios using AVPlayer

Tags: ios, avplayer

i am trying to develop a small app which should stream audio from a particular link. I am using AVPlayer for that but i dont know why its not working. Tried google but nothing seems to be relevant there. Kindly Help.. thank you

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://108.166.161.206:8826/stream.mp3"];

self->playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
self->player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
self->player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
[player play];

}
```

Comment: check this https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer

Comment: i checked that but not able to understand properly as i am very new to this field. Kindly suggest some simple example.

Comment: This might be a duplicate question. Found this for you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13131177/streaming-mp3-audio-with-avplayer

Answer (score 0):

don`t know why you first init your player with a playeritem and after that init it with an NSURL. 
Anyways, here is the way to go:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad{

    player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:
             [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxx/yourfile.mp3"]];

    [player addObserver:self forKeyPath@"status" options:0 context:nil];
}

- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath 
                                ofObject:(id)object 
                                change:(NSDictionary  *)change 
                                context:(void *)context {

    if (object == player && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
        if (player.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
            [player play];
        }
        if (player.status == AVPlayerStatusFailed) {
            NSLog(@"Something went wrong: %@", player.error);
        }
    }
}
```

The [AV Foundation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH3-SW1) should be a good start point to find out how the AVPlayer stuff works

Answer (score 0):

this line isn't necessary `self->player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://108.166.161.206:8826/stream.mp3"];

self->playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
self->player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
[player play];

}
```

also don't forget to add the NSAllowsArbitraryLoads key to info.plist

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can try this with AVAudioPlayer :

```
NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                   [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://108.166.161.206:8826/stream.mp3"]];
NSError *error = nil;
self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:fileData error:&error];
[self.player play];
```

Comment: The AVAudioPlayer class does not provide support for streaming audio based on HTTP URL's. The URL used with initWithContentsOfURL: must be a File URL (file://). That is, a local path.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1634/_index.html