# Streaming Audio File from HTTP URL

Tags: audio, streaming, avaudioplayer, audio-streaming, avplayer

I am struggling to stream hosted audio files like the one below:
http://res.cloudinary.com/karmo/raw/upload/v1415468388/kdzu36kr8t7aowkeqrn7.mp4

I have tried using `AVPLayer` with the `initWithURL` and while I do not get any errors I never hear any audio play back.

```
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://res.cloudinary.com/karmo/raw/upload/v1415468388/kdzu36kr8t7aowkeqrn7.mp4"];
player = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithURL:url];
songPlayer = player;
```

Any previous StackOverflow examples I have found I have the same issue... no errors but I never hear any audio playback

[Streaming mp3 audio with AVPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13131177/streaming-mp3-audio-with-avplayer)

[Audio streaming in ios using AVPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16076128/audio-streaming-in-ios-using-avplayer)

What am I missing...