# Can't get AVAudioPlayer to Play

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I've followed every resource that I can find, and I don't know why this isn't working. I'm trying to play it on the simulator. Also, I have verified that my urlString is accurate and that it plays when pasted into a browser. What am I missing?

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>

@end
```

.m file

```
@interface SessionsListViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
@end

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", AUDIO_URL, @"test.mp3"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSError *err = nil;
    self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&err];

    [self.audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [self.audioPlayer setDelegate:self];
     self.audioPlayer.volume = 1.0;
    [self.audioPlayer play];


}
```

Comment: What does a log of url show?

Comment: Don't you need a "www" and/or an "http://" at the beginning of that? Browsers automatically add that for you, I don't think that's true for initWithContentsOfURL:.

Comment: Also, I think this is probably a typo, but there should be an @end after your property declaration in the class extension.

Comment: Yes. it's a typo. I've edited the post.

Comment: That's a SO formatting thing. They took my text (which included http://www) and displayed it as a hyperlink without that part. Not sure why or how to correct it, but that full URL is in the string.

Comment: I still can't get "h t t p : / / w w w ." to appear at the front!

Comment: Here is the best answer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13131177/streaming-mp3-audio-with-avplayer