# Play notification sound using URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avplayer

I want my application to play notification sound through `URL`. My custom sound file lies at a particular working `URL`. So, I want my app to use that link to notify user about notification.

I've tried `AVPlayer`,since it plays sound files through URL's [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13131177/streaming-mp3-audio-with-avplayer)

The `AVPlayer` code is working when I call it using `[self playselectedsong]` (plz check code provided in above link) in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` of `AppDelegate` and `viewDidLoad` function of other views.

Whenever the notification arrives(`didReceiveRemoteNotification`) with an audio file `URL`,which then I add into the `AVPlayer`,the sound isn't playing.Only the text notification is shown.

Comment: People are still down-voting this old question. The down-votes will not have any constructive effect now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No it is not possible to play a sound  on remote notification unless you have it on Main bundle. [Check Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html)

> For remote notifications in iOS, you can specify a custom sound that
> iOS plays when it presents a local or remote notification for an
> application. The sound files must be in the main bundle of the client
> application.

2. Even if you add a sound file on your main bundle , that file can not be longer than 30 seconds

> Custom sounds must be under 30 seconds when played. If a custom sound
> is over that limit, the default system sound is played instead.

I hope it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

The sound must come from a file in the app bundle.

> **sound** | 
>   *string* | The name of a sound file in the app bundle. The sound in this file is
>   played as an alert. If the sound file doesn’t exist or default is
>   specified as the value, the default alert sound is played....

See Apple Reference [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly, it is possible to play audio from a remote file now. I'll copy the content of the message here in case it gets removed. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/118404

> Correct Answer by KevinE on Jul 30, 2019 5:11 PM
>
> The specifics of how your app should work are going to vary a lot
>   depending on  your specific use cases and app design, but our general
>   recommendation for  push to talk apps is that you shift to using
>   standard push notifications  instead of PushKit for message delivery. 
>   More specifically, on the receiver  side your Notification Service
>   Extension should download the relevant audio and  attach that sound to
>   your particular message.
>
> To support that approach, starting in iOS 13, the system looks for
>   possible  sound files in the apps group container(s) as well as the
>   preexisting search  locations.  The documentation hasn't been updated
>   for this yet  (), but there is header file
>   documentation describing  the details in the comments for
>   "soundNamed:" in "UNNotificationSound.h":
>
> // The sound file to be played for the notification. The sound must be
>   in the  Library/Sounds folder of the app's data container or the
>   Library/Sounds folder  of an app group data container. If the file is
>   not found in a container, the  system will look in the app's bundle.
>
> Breaking that down in detail, we look for sound files in the following
>   order and locations:
>
> 1. Your apps direct container in "Library/Sounds".
> 2. Your apps group(s) directory in a directory named "Library/Sounds"
> 3. Your apps bundle
>
> The main things to keep in mind here:
>
> Directory #2 is "Library/Sounds", not just "Sounds".  You'll need to
>   create a  "Library" directory with a "Sounds" directory inside it, not
>   just a "Sounds" directory. The apps direct container is still the
>   first place we'll look, so you'll need  to be careful about how you
>   name your files.  I would recommend either using  the group directory
>   for all sounds or following a naming convention for the  two different
>   locations so that they never collide.  Your Network Service  Extension
>   can't see the contents of directory #1, so it can't know whether or 
>   not a particular name will collide.