# How to play audio from live streaming in backgroung iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, mpmovieplayercontroller, background-audio

Hai i am playing mp3 from live streaming using `MPMoviePlayerController` but it doesn't play when app is running in background. and it stop playing when the phone is locked. please tell me how can i play live streaming audio both in background and phone is locked. suggest me asap please.

I am using `MPMoviePlayerController` instead of `AvAudioPlayer`. because of `AvAudioPlayer` doesn't support network streaming [reference.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1634/_index.html)

NOTE:

language - Swift 2.0

**UPDATE 1**

**Finally coded with AVPlayer. But It doesn't play my audio from url [This mp3 need to play in my app.](http://www.raagam.co/4256s5f46ht4he4r6/2016/Achcham%20Enbathu%20Madamaiyada/Thalli%20Pogathey.mp3) My code is**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    audioUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.raagam.co/4256s5f46ht4he4r6/2016/Achcham%20Enbathu%20Madamaiyada/Thalli%20Pogathey.mp3")!
    let avAsset = AVURLAsset(URL: audioUrl)
    let avPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: avAsset)

    avPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: avPlayerItem)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.playerItemDidReachEnd), name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: avPlayer.currentItem)
    avPlayer.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {

    if (object!.isEqual(avPlayer) && keyPath=="status"){
        print("Observer")
        if avPlayer.status == AVPlayerStatus.ReadyToPlay{
            print("ReadyToPlay")
            avPlayer.play();
        }else if avPlayer.status == AVPlayerStatus.Failed{
            print("Failed")
        }else if avPlayer.status == AVPlayerStatus.Unknown{
            print("Unknown")
        }
    }
}

func playerItemDidReachEnd(){
        print("Finished")
}
```

I use this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13131177/streaming-mp3-audio-with-avplayer?lq=1/13156942#13156942)

When I run this code. It prints **ReadyToPlay**. But mp3 is not playing.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by enabling background audio in your Project > Capabilities pane:

[image: Capabilities pane in Xcode]

then hitting play.

But instead of `MPMoviePlayerController` or `AVAudioPlayer`, use  `AVPlayer`.

Comment: I updated the question, Avplayer also not working in my case.