# camera streaming between website and iphone

Tags: iphone

i was wondering how would i be able to stream a video from a website to my iphone.
I dont know how to stream my videos to an iphone. since flash isnt supported on the iphone what would be the best approach to do this.

thanks.

Comment: From the SO faq: "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."  http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: @ctrahey — Please reread the question. It says "from a website to my iphone", not the other way around. There was no mention of the camera on the iphone (before editing there was mention that the source of the video was a laptop's webcam; I assume the editing was to focus on the problem of the format needed to support iOS as a client, making the question clearer and less broad).

Answer (score 2):

iOS supports (as a client) HTTP Live Streaming (as described [in this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592485/http-live-streaming)) which should suit your purposes.

Comment: thank you for your help man this resolved half of my issue.