# FFMpeg-iOS usage issue

Tags: ios, audio, ffmpeg

I've compiled the ffmpeg for iOS with the instructions from [FFmpeg-iOS](https://github.com/kewlbear/FFmpeg-iOS-build-script). I am trying to use it for wav to mp3 conversion with the help of [FFmpegWrapper](https://github.com/OpenWatch/FFmpegWrapper). It gives me the following error: `Invalid audio stream. Exactly one MP3 audio stream is required.` Did anybody has the same issue?

---

### Edit:

The code I am trying to use for the converting

```
NSString *inPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"record" ofType:@"wav"];
NSString *outPath = @"/Users/someuser/Desktop/out.mp3";

FFmpegWrapper *wrapper = [[FFmpegWrapper alloc] init];
[wrapper convertInputPath:inPath outputPath:outPath options:@{kFFmpegInputFormatKey: @"wav", kFFmpegOutputFormatKey: @"mp3"} progressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, uint64_t totalBytesRead, uint64_t totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
    NSLog(@":)");
} completionBlock:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Complete");
}];
```

Comment: You're trying to store an AAC stream in a MP3 container, would be my guess.

Either store the result as `"${i%.mp3}-ENCODED.aac"` or switch `-c:a aac` to `-c:a libmp3lame`

Comment: I've seen here on stackoverflow this answer, but my issue is that I cannot use the ffmpeg from command line. How can this be done from code?

Comment: whats your trying code?

Comment: @combo_ci I just added my code as an edit of the post.

Comment: I think you must search for how to configure  FFmpegWrapper software...FFmpegWrapper must have a file or a configure menue that you could change ffmpeg setting..or are FFmpegWrapper use last version of ffmpeg?

Comment: for example see the answer of [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30912542/mp4-to-hls-using-ffmpeg) he change duration of hls in a configuration od FFmpegWaper

Comment: I am going to check this, thanks!

Comment: I think you gave me a good hint. It takes time until I fully check it, but I will return with an answer.