# How to securely play .m3u8 streaming file from AWS S3 using CloudFront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, aws-php-sdk

I'm using CloudFront Signed URL to display images and videos from S3 to be secured.

It works well on images and other videos except for .m3u8 file.

I used AWS PHP SDK and here's my code.

```
<?php
    // Instantiate the CloudFront client.
    $cloudFrontClient = new CloudFrontClient(array(
        'region'        => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'version'       => 'latest',
        'http'          => [ 'verify' => false ],
        'credentials'   => array(
            'key'           => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret'        => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        )
    ));
    
    // Create a signed URL for the resource.
    $resourceKey = 'https://abcdefg.cloudfront.net/test/file_1000k.m3u8';

    $expires =  time() + 3600;
    $signedUrl = $cloudFrontClient->getSignedUrl([
        'url'         => $resourceKey,
        'expires'     => $expires,
        'private_key' => public_path() . '/pk-ABCD123.pem',
        'key_pair_id' => 'ABCD123ABCD123ABCD123'
    ]);
?>

<video id="hls-example" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="640" height="480" controls>
    <source src="<?php echo $signedUrl; ?>" type="application/x-mpegURL">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.2.3/video.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo asset('public/assets/js/videojs-contrib-hls.min.js'); ?>"></script>
<script>
    var player = videojs('hls-example');
    player.play();
</script>
```

If I'm not mistaken, it doesn't play because we also need to sign the segmented files (`.ts`) inside the `.m3u8` file.

How do I dynamically change it?

Is there any way we can play `.m3u8` file securely so that users can't use the direct link access to download the file?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good AWS article to help you decide between (1) cookies and (2) signed URLs: -

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-choosing-signed-urls-cookies.html

I initially looked at the cookie approach but opted for individually signing each URL inside the HLS manifest file.  I use `ffmpeg` to convert a MP4 file to HLS (e.g. [Mp4 to HLS using ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30912542/mp4-to-hls-using-ffmpeg)) and the HLS manifest will be something like: -

```java
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:17
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:16.683333,
my-video0.ts
#EXTINF:8.341667,
my-video1.ts
#EXTINF:8.341667,
my-video2.ts

...

#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

You would individually sign each segment e.g.

```java
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:17
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:16.683333,
https://cqtgd3b9n5c6qp.cloudfront.net/my-video0.ts?Expires=1609499278&Key-Pair-Id=AIRPEGWQPKAIQ7O3SPLI&Signature=KUvRsV-OpJ014ZQ0dLZF....
#EXTINF:8.341667,
https://cqtgd3b9n5c6qp.cloudfront.net/my-video1.ts?Expires=1609499278&Key-Pair-Id=AIRPEGWQPKAIQ7O3SPLI&Signature=KlVQsz5TVzhEQ8LKs1ZW....
#EXTINF:8.341667,
https://cqtgd3b9n5c6qp.cloudfront.net/my-video2.ts?Expires=1609499278&Key-Pair-Id=AIRPEGWQPKAIQ7O3SPLI&Signature=VR1MBzq~pVsBfOzjZa~M....

...

#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

Simple search / replace will dynamically generate this file.

Signing each URL will takes a bit of processing so I add an Expires header (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expires) to the HTTP response when returning the HLS manifest.  This ensures subsequent calls in the browser use the cached copy which massively increases performance.

> **NOTE** - it's important the expires in the HTTP response is (slightly) less than the Expires in the signed URL.

I find individually signing each URL is more secure and you don't need to worry about domains etc but probably slightly more complex (code wise) to implement.

Answer (score 0):

CloudFront signed URLs work great when it is just one file, but like you have discovered it is a problem when you have multiple resources.

For this reason the recommended approach is to use [signed CloudFront cookies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-cookies.html).

By doing this you only need to sign once to allow all resources from a specific CloudFront distribution and do not need to bother with the signing process on each page load.

Comment: Ahh, Do you have an idea on how to implement that?

Comment: Its a similar process to the signed URLs, you use the CLI or SDK. This page has more information on implementation details:https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-cookies.html#private-content-overview-sample-code-cookies

Answer (score -1):

For anyone who might be struggling with this as of **2023**, you can use the [hls.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hls.js) library to stream `.m3u8` files with almost *zero* config (available via NPM, too).

> HLS.js is a JavaScript library that implements an HTTP Live Streaming client. It relies on HTML5 video and MediaSource Extensions for playback.

It's as simple as providing the library with the `.m3u8` playlist URL and treating the `video` element as you usually would.

The simplest implementation would be as follows:

```js
// Note that here the Hls class is not instantiated yet. You do this later.
if(Hls.isSupported()){
    let video = document.getElementById("hls-example");
    let hls = new Hls();

    let videoURL = "https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8";
    // Load the m3u8 playlist
    hls.loadSource(videoURL);
    // Bind the video element to the media.
    hls.attachMedia(video);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js"></script>
<video id="hls-example" width="640" height="360" controls></video>
```

You can read more in the [docs](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/blob/HEAD/docs/API.md) here.