# Which Native iOS API can be used to stream and play audio data in my application?

Tags: ios, swift3, avaudioplayer, audio-streaming

I'm interested in building a iOS application similar to wynk.The app will be having a list of songs. On clicking any option, it will start streaming that music file from the server. I don't want to use any third Party API. Any help/ suggestion will be of great help. I'm using xCode 8.0 with swift 3.

Comment: Please see [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple provides HTTP Live Streaming (HLS) for audio/video streaming:
https://developer.apple.com/streaming/,

At the start of the streaming session, the client downloads a master .m3u8 playlist file containing the metadata for the various sub-streams which are available. Then decides what to download from the media files available, based on predefined factors such as device type, resolution, data rate, size, etc.

Apple provides sample code on how to play and persist HTTP Live Streams hosted on remote servers:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/HLSCatalog/Listings/HLSCatalog_AssetListTableViewCell_swift.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017320-HLSCatalog_AssetListTableViewCell_swift-DontLinkElementID_4

also check this answer on HLS here, you'll get the whole picture: [HTTP LIve Streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592485/http-live-streaming)

AVFoundation for playback 
https://developer.apple.com/av-foundation/

```
import AVFoundation
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        let videoURL = NSURL(string: "your_video_url")
        guard let player = AVPlayer(URL: videoURL) else { return }
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        player.play()
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for all the stuff... I'm pretty sure that it will help in my work.

Comment: @Peeyushkarnwal no problem, good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AVPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayer) which is a controller object used to manage the playback and timing of a media asset. It provides the interface to control the player’s transport behavior such as its ability to play, pause, change the playback rate, and seek to various points in time within the media’s timeline. You can use an AVPlayer to play local and remote file-based media, such as QuickTime movies and MP3 audio files, as well as audiovisual media served using HTTP Live Streaming.