# How to stream live video from camera in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, video, live-streaming

How can I stream a live video from a camera to an iOS application.
Let me know what are the possible way for stream video from the camera to cloud and view in iOS application.

Comment: Since when has the iPhone or the iPad become a web server?

Comment: did you found any sample code to implment the same, Please share if you found any

Comment: @ParvBhasker: you can use AVAPlayer for streaming m3u8 url.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It depends on what your camera supports. There are two ways to implement live streaming in an ios application.

1. HTTP Live Streaming :- HTTP Live Streaming (also known as HLS) is an
   HTTP-based media streaming communications protocol that provides
   mechanisms that are scalable and adaptable to different networks.
   HLS works by breaking down a video file into a sequence of small
   HTTP-based file downloads, with each download loading one short
   chunk of a video file.

   Reference Links : https://developer.apple.com/streaming/
   https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MediaPlaybackGuide/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/HTTPLiveStreaming/HTTPLiveStreaming.html
   [HTTP LIve Streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592485/http-live-streaming)
   https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html
2. RTSP Streaming :- The Real Time Streaming Protocol (RTSP) is a
   network control protocol designed for use in entertainment and
   communications systems to control streaming media servers. The
   protocol is used for establishing and controlling media sessions
   between end points. There are third party library available which
   can be used for RTSP streaming Like FFMPEG, VideoKit etc.

   Reference Links :
                      https://www.ffmpeg.org 
                      https://iosvideokit.com

Answer (score -2):

There are several platforms out there where you can record and distribute your recording and share it with friends. Some of them are

1. UStream
2. Live Stream
3. Youtube

Youtube specifically has extensive documentation on what apps to download and how to setup your encoder and how to distribute your playback URL. The link to their documentation is here
https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2853700

4. Facebook

This will be more specific to distribution only within the facebook network. So, if you want to publicly distribute your live stream, you should probably go with one of the others.

There would definitely be a lot more other platforms. But, these are the ones that come to mind.

Comment: I am looking fro streaming video to an iOS application.

Comment: I think you should clearly state what is this application you're trying to stream to. Your question is extremely open ended. So, the answer you'll get will also be open ended like this. 

Maybe you should start with what iOS application you're talking about.
Is this application something you wrote?
Or do you want solutions at tools/apps level?
Give more details on what your whole setup looks like end to end.

Comment: I hope , I have mentioned that streaming a live video from a camera, and view to an iOS application. The video must save to a cloud server and stream the same to an iOS application.

Comment: That's a solution to what?  Does video distribution through YouTube or Facebook require Swift knowledge?

Comment: Well. If the question is directed to me, I have to say, I felt that the question was quite open ended and hence, I gave an open ended answer.

Since @VineeshTP has marked the previous answer as the most suitable for him, it looks like the question was more about streaming protocols he could use to develop his application. 

To begin with, that requirement wasn't clear. And now since it is clear, and has been answered, there's nothing left to say here.

Comment: @ElTomato: I have to stream the video via iOS applicaion

Comment: @MukundManikarnike: I asked How can I achieve video streaming in mobile application.

Comment: @VineeshTP Well, yes. That's right. I understood it as some test application that you're trying get you feed to send out to a server. Wasn't sure if you were writing the app. 

Since you're writing your own app, you should explore live streaming platforms that are exposed as a service, such as 
Brightcove, Livestream API, Wowza and so on. HLS, RTSP and so on are protocols. I'm assuming you're not keen on writing all of that. If you are, then great. But, just thought I'd give you some these sources as well.